# can't connect to azure cosmos mongodb api from mongo-express inside kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, mongo-express

I have the following deployment settings for the mongo explored pod.

- name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_CA_FILE
  value: /usr/local/conf/test.pem
  - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN
  value: 'true'
  - name: ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_READONLY
  value: 'true'
  - name: ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME
  - name: ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD
  - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT
  value: '10255'
  - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
  value: tfex.documents.azure.com
  - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
  value: tfex
  - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
  value: >-password
  - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL
  value: >-
  mongodb://tfex:password@tfex.documents.azure.com:10255/db?ssl=true&sslverifycertificate=false&replicaSet=globaldb

and it is throwing following error and pod didn't up

MongoError: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What Mongo server version is your Cosmos account configured for? 3.2 or 3.6? The endpoints for each of these is different. 3.2 is documents.azure.com and 3.6 is mongo.cosmos.azure.com

Comment: I tried with both versions/endpoints. Both are throwing the same error at the time of POD initialization.

Comment: I could resolve the issue myself. we must provide a blank value to the following environment variable ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER, then only supplied ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL value will be utilized. Thank you @MarkBrown for responding to the issue quickly.